# Path for file upload using remote host, in war file deployment condition

Tags: tomcat, exception, servlets, deployment

I have made an java web application and i have deployed the war file on the server. I am having a file upload mechanism in my web application. I am passing the path where the file to be stored using context path
The below give code i am using is on my local server

```
   <context-param>
    <description>Location to store uploaded file</description>
     <param-name>file-upload</param-name>
     <param-value>E:\my work\Tomcat\webapps\images
     </param-value>
   </context-param>
```

This code is working fine as the image is stored on the local disk location But the problem starts when I change the location for the remote server

```
 <context-param>
   <description>Location to store uploaded file</description>
   <param-name>file-upload</param-name>
   <param-value>httpdocs/img/
  </param-value>
 </context-param>
```

I have changed the code before deploying it on my remote Host i have got the directory structure as follows

```
Root directory
 .plesk
 cgi-bin
 error_docs
 httpdocs
 logs

 After uploading the file i am getting the following exception
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: httpdocs\img\ankit.jpg (The system cannot find     the path specified) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) 
 at  java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown  Source) 
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:416)
```

So my question is what should be the path that i can provide to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Exception is quite clear. How exactly are you sure that the given path exists? You've nowhere confirmed that the given path exists. You only said that there's a `httpdocs` folder, but not `httpdocs/img`.

Comment: 'img' folder is also inside the httpdocs i have checked it.